pip install fontconfig getting SyntaxError : Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'
I am trying to install the fontconfig but it gives the following error. Is there any other way for installing this pack?
Collecting fontconfig
  Downloading fontconfig-0.1.zip (121 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 122.0/122.0 kB 70.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gh6zzwr6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gh6zzwr6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gh6zzwr6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gh6zzwr6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 9
          exec line in glb
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'. Did you mean exec(...)?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


It seems this version of the package was written for Python 2.x. Try to find a version for 3.x

The linked duplicate is focused on how you'd go about fixing the specific problem in the code to be compatible with Python 3. Of course, it's almost certainly full of other problems -- but we can only address the specific items asked.

fontconfig didn't update for a while.  You can use fontconfig-py or use GObjectIntrospection based TypeLib.
import gi

gi.require_version('fontconfig', '2.0')

from gi.repository import fontconfig

# you can use fontconfig module now.

I don't know its typelib is complete or not. But you can edit its 'gir' file and contribute back to be usable for a wider audience.

Note that fontconfig-py currrently supports linux and macOs (https://pypi.org/project/fontconfig-py/)

Thanks. any suggestion for windows?

I have no windows pc. But give msys2 a try. It has python3 and native fontconfig package.

Thank you. It seems that resolving this issue is not straightforward, and it may require modifications to the package itself or finding another way for my program. so I have marked your response as the accepted answer.
